# DVI cable trouble

Tags: display, vga, dvi

I have a monitor E2360S that has double link digital DVI interface, also i have three graphics cards: and asus gtx 560 ti, gigabyte radeon 7870 and some very old radeon that has a VGA interface. Here's the problem: with VGA cable on the old card everything works, with double link DVI cable from work 560 and 7870 work also, but i bought two single link digital DVI's and none of them work, i get no image at all on the monitor. I got on of these cables to work and here it only shows bios, when windows starts to boot i get no image also. Please help! Is there some type of configuration i need to do on the monitor or what ?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You'll have to tell us the screen resolutions which you tried of course. Also, did you look for DVI configuration options in the graphics card config software?

Comment: 1920x1080 is the resolution. I have last drivers installed for both 560 and 7870 installed on that PC.

Comment: Are you sure the cables arn't the problem? They might just be problematic.

Comment: I don't know what to think now... I'll go and check them in support again...

Comment: My Q was not whether you use the latest drivers, but whether you looked for DVI configuration options in the card config software. A _huge_ difference, one might say.

Comment: I'm sorry, but idk where that is... Could you elaborate pls ?

Comment: And I here don't know what your Q is. My hint is simply that I have at least one system where I can explicitly configure DVI output to Dual Link, such that I wouldn't be sure that it will work with a signle link cable. But I'm kindly asking you to figure it out for yourself with your given HW using the manuals, because I have pretty different HW and SW.

Comment: Well ok, i guess i'll grab the dual link cable again and try to search for smth in the settings, but i really don't know what i'm supposed to be looking for... Thx for you help.

Comment: You have all the keywords: DVI, single link, dual link. If there's no setting for DVI for you then there's no setting for DVI for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bought a dual link cable and everything works for whatever reason, because single link is supposed to work to.